# How to set auto insert new line and indent in Vim when use the auto close in pair

Tags: vim, indentation

I found a Vim auto pair plugin called [vim-autoclose](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose). It works great just like other IDEs. For example, when you type `{` it gives you `{|}` (the "|" represents the cursor). Then, if you press "Enter", the `{|}` becomes:

```
{

      |

}
```

This is what I need, but unfortunately it disables my Chinese input method application,so I have to abandon it.

I have tried other autoclose plugins, but none of them can auto close in this way. I found a way to make auto close work like the way above.

```
:autocmd FileType c,java,javascript ino <buffer> { <C-G>u{<CR>}<Esc>O<C-T>
```

But it has a problem with the shiftwidth. For example, if I `:set shiftwidth=4` the new line between `{}` will have an 8 space indent. The indent in the new line doubles the shiftwidth.

My question is how to set the indent of the new line to the same space indent of shiftwidth?

Comment: Bug report on vim-autoclose: https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose/issues/38

Answer (score 0):

```
inoremap { {<CR><CR>}<C-o>k<C-o>S
```

seems to work.

Comment: Not yeah.It can not insert a new line an auto indent

Comment: I've edited my answer. I should have used `S` instead of `<Tab>`.

Comment: Also did you try [delimitmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2754)?

Answer (score 0):

After setting `set ai` and `set smartindent` in vimrc

Use the following

`inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<ESC>O`

should work. The last character is `capital O`, not zero.