# Vim removes auto tabs if I don't enter anything in line with inserted auto tabs

Tags: vim

A very simple example: I want to write a function, and there are already several levels of indentation (tabs before the word "function"). I first write:

```
1     function doCoolStuff() {
2 
3     }
```

then go up one line from line 3 to line 2 and start typing the contents of the function. However, vim doesn't allow me to do so by removing the auto inserted tabs on line 2 after I type the bracket on line 3 and go up one line. So I have to insert tabs manually each time I write a new function. That's how it goes:

When I type the function's head and press enter, it looks like this:

```
1     function doCoolStuff() {
2     ▊
3
```

Vim correctly inserts auto tabs on line 2.

**But!**

Then I press Enter, type a closing bracket and go up one line. **I expect it to be like this:**

```
1     function doCoolStuff() {
2     ▊
3     }
```

**but it turns out to be like this, without any tabs on line 2:**

```
1     function doCoolStuff() {
2 ▊
3     }
```

Seems to be that vim sees that there is a line consisting entirely of tab characters and removes the tab characters. How do I disallow vim to remove trailing tabs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is most likely the results of some kind of [autoindent or cindent](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code#Methods_for_automatic_indentation). There isn't really any tab or space there until you type something.  So when you leave that line, it is not actually stripping a tab or space out, because it wasn't there in the first place.

What I usually do is move up to the line above where I want to start typing and then press <kbd>o</kbd> to start editing in the next line (and the autoindent handles the positioning correctly).

Answer (score 4):

The answer is to enter something on the line and delete it again, because ViM will *not* auto-remove the tab characters in that case:

```
:inoremap <CR> <CR>x<BS>
```

does the job. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7413117/589206) thread for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You could use DelimitMate or some other auto-pairing script or something like [this answer of mine on a similar problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12112286/546861)